# Converting CSV to Parquet in spark without writing/saving it

Tags: csv, apache-spark, parquet

I am trying to convert a CSV to Parquet and then use it for other purposes and I couldn't find how to do it without saving it, I've only seen this kind of structure to convert and it always writes/saves the data:

```py
data = spark.read.load(sys.argv[1], format="csv", sep="|", inferSchema="true", header="true")

data.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(sys.argv[2])
```

Am I missing something? I am also happy with scala solutions.
Thanks!

I've tried to play with the mode option in `"write"` but it didn't help.

Comment: Parquet is a file format so talking about converting a csv to a parquet does not really make sense if you keep the data in memory. Regardless of the input/output format, spark will store the data in memory the same way. What do you want do to with the "parquet data"?

Comment: Thanks,

I want to analyze how much the csv to parquet conversion itself takes (from a compute prospective) vs how much the saving takes time (which is an not compute, but I/O)

Comment: So you want to know how much time you save by writing compressed data (parquet) and how much you lose by compressing it? Spark is built to handle datasets that do not fit in memory so when it writes a parquet file, it does not compress all the data and then write it. It does that on the fly so that's going to be tricky to measure the two separately.